# Removing the default pages when adding a domain via Plesk

Tags: apache, plesk, dedicated-server

whenever I add a new domain into my new Plesk control panel on my dedicated server it creates a whole bunch of test files in the cgi-bin, httpdocs and httpsdocs.

There must be some setting somewhere where I can tell Plesk not to do this?
I've done a good Google search but must now turn to the StackOverflow masses :)

Yours,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found it (and feel a bit stupid!)
/var/www/vhosts/.skel/0/

Hope that helps someone :)